# How do I align the view to the nearest global axis?

Tags: 3d-view

Is there a button or a shortcut that will align the view to the nearest global axis?

For example:
You use the shortcut that will the align view so that you're looking down the X axis.
Then you rotate the view slightly (say 10 degrees, for example).
Is there a shortcut that will snap the view back to the X axis because it's the closest one?

If I had manually rotated the view more than 45 degrees away from the X axis and then used the shortcut that I'm seeking, I would like it to snap to the closest of the other two global axes.

In Unity there's a control in the top right-hand corner of the view that lets you quickly align the view to a specific axis. The control rotates with the view, meaning that if you keep clicking on the handle on the right-hand side of the control, the view will keep rotating around the pivot in the same direction.

If I have to install a plugin to enable this, I'm willing to do so.

[image]

Comment: If you use Shift+Numpad 1, 3 or 7 to align view to selected face and then press Numpad 4 or 6 it will rotate around current viewport camera location, so viewport will continue being aligned with the axis specified above

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but it would not align the view to the nearest global axis, unless I've misunderstood you.

Aligning the view to a selected face when you're trying to align the view to the global axis would require that the face is already aligned to the global axis.

Besides, before pressing Shift+Numpad 1, 3 or 7, I would have to first check which axis I'm looking down and then decide whether to press 1, 3 or 7.

Comment: I don't believe there is a built-in shortcut that does what you want but if you hold the Alt key down while tumbling, the view will snap to orthographic views.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/192527/how-to-snap-object-local-rotation-to-its-nearest-global-axis-with-python aligns a mesh to nearest global axis, could be edited to align view instead.

Answer (score 2):

Use snap view. Hold the middle mouse button to start rotating the view. Then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>. If the view is close enough to snap, it will. If not, it snaps to another 45 angle view.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a number pad it is quite easy otherwise it is under view

http://www.blender.hu/tutor/kdoc/Blender_Cheat_Sheet.pdf

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't think it answers the question.
Which button would you press to align the view to the nearest axis?

Comment: Did you even check the link? I don't think there is a shortcut to align the view to the nearest axis, probably because it would need extra logic but the number pad is used for the view.

Comment: if you really need to set the view to weird angles you can use the camera for it.

Comment: Yes, I did check the link. This isn't the first time I've looked through that cheat sheet.

I'm confused. Why would you say "If you have a number pad it is quite easy" if you don't think there is a shortcut to align the view to the nearest axis? Were you talking about rotating the view around the object when you wrote that?